# Está trazendo a coluna inteira e não somente de um id especifico

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc

Estou tentando pegar o ultimo km registrado no banco de um veiculo especifico, porém ele me trás todos os km e não de um veiculo especifico.

Meu Controller:

```
 var Rota = ckm.ConsultaProduto(viewModel.NumCarroId);

        var maiorRota = Rota.OrderByDescending(c => c.Km).First();

            if (maiorRota != null && viewModel.Km < maiorRota.Km)
            // Aqui se não tiver valor para fazer comparação (maiorRota != null), ele ira registrar.
            // Ele ira fazer a comparação e ira salvar se estiver de acordo(viewModel.Km < maiorRota.Km).
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Km_Atual.Invalido", "A quilometragem precisa ser maior que a anterior");
            }
```

Minha query onde pega as informações do banco:

```
public IList<Abastecimento> ConsultaProduto(int Id)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT a FROM Abastecimento a";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Abastecimento>();
    }
```

Estou tentando fazer com que ele pegue o ultimo km no banco e depois compare com atual, se for maior ele ira registra, se não ira ocorrer um erro

Comment: Guilherme você precisa usar o parâmetro Id como filtro no método ConsultaProduto. Exemplo: string hql = "SELECT CampoX, CampoY FROM Abastecimento WHERE CampoFKdeVeiculo = " + Id;

Comment: Sou novo no c#.net com mvc, não sei como aplica na hql a opção de ele interferi na minha view, normalmente aplico a where no controller e utilizo a viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o @Renan comentou você não está filtrando a sua consulta, listando todos os resultados e depois selecionando aquele com o [Km] maior... Já havia apontado isso em outra pergunta sua.

Ou você altera o seu método de consulta ou faz o filtro na controller, como você prefere...

```
var Rota = ckm.ConsultaProduto(0)
              .Where(x=> x.Id == viewModel.NumCarroId).ToList();
```

> EDIT:
>   Inclusíve mudei o valor passado como parâmetro para 0 para demonstrar de que não faz difrença nenhuma...

Agora corrigindo o seu método de consulta, mas poderá trazer impacto para o resto da sua aplicação... não tenho como saber onde como você está utilizando ele em outros lugares.

```
public IList<Abastecimento> ConsultaProduto(int Id)
{
    string hql = "SELECT a FROM Abastecimento a WHERE [SUA_COLUNA_DE_ID] ="+ Id;
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
    return query.List<Abastecimento>();
}
```

Agora sim você pode chamar o método  na sua controller utilizando o valor da model

```
var Rota = ckm.ConsultaProduto(viewModel.NumCarroId)
```

Comment: Isso ira fazer com que eu filtre o valor do veiculo que eu desejo, pelo ToList?

Comment: pelo Where()... mas o seu método ConsultaProduto vai continuar errado... você passa um parâmetro para ele que deveria ser o filtro mas não utiliza em lugar nenhum...

Comment: o certo seria aplica o where pelo hql então, assim para ele filtra e deixa menos lento o processo, e filtra de modo certo?

Comment: Exato, mas o Where no SQL, na declaração da string hql

Comment: Começa a aplica isso no sistema, estava vendo que muitos sistemas e exercícios aplicam o where no hql, para ter menos processo e agiliza, o meu problema é mais fazer ele pega o valor da view para o where faze a filtragem

Comment: Uma duvida, ali na sua coluna de Id, pode ser chave estrangeira ou teria que implementar mais alguma coisa?

Comment: [SUA_COLUNA_DE_ID] é a coluna da tabela Abastecimento que você quer comparar se é igual ao parâmetro Id que o método recebe como entrada

Comment: Consegui efetuar a implantação, e só mexendo nessa consulta, já senti que o processo de procura e adiciona fico mais rapido

Comment: Faça essa revisão em todos os seus métodos de consulta ao banco.